# Python-Local Scope and Global Scope

Tags: python-3.x

```
stored=0
def store(arg):
    stored=arg
    return stored
y=store(22)
print(y)
print(stored)
```

Output:

```
22
0
```

I really want to understand why `print(stored)`is not equal to 22.Thank you so much.

Comment: Because you didn't declare it global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function isn't altering `stored` that's located in the *global* scope. It is creating a local variable `stored` inside the function, assigning a value to it and returning it. The assignment affects the *local* `stored`, *it doesn't touch the global `stored`*.

You can make it refer to the global `stored` by using the `global` statement:

```
def store(arg):
    global stored
    stored = arg
    return stored
```

Adding the `global <var_name>` statement tells Python that `stored` is referring to a name that exists in the *global* scope; any assignments/modifications to `stored` inside the function `store` will now alter the corresponding name in the global scope.